# smtplib.SMTPRecipientRefused error while sending email

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have a **basic Email code** which looks like this:

```
#sendmail function to send multiple attachments to multiple users at the   same time 
def sendMail(to, fro, subject, text, files=[], server="localhost"):
    assert type(to) == list
    assert type(files) == list
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fro
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'html'))
#    print "Obtained Files:",files

    for file in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open(file.strip(' '), "rb").read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'
                       % os.path.basename(file))
        msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(fro, to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```

**Error I am receiving:**

```
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'firstname.lastname@work.com': (553, '5.5.4 <firstname.lastname@work.com>... Domain name required for sender address a.b@work.com')}
```

What is the reason of the following error and how can I resolve the same? Have been stuck on this since many hours !!!
PS: **my port 25 is working and I am using python 2.7.9 and Ubuntu 15.04**

Comment: `Domain name required for sender address` - looks like you are setting `fro` (from address) to `systest-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro`, and it's failing because that's not an email address.

Comment: I am sorry for tht domain name systest-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro. I was just trying some test cases. 
Also, i am not receiving the same error now !! It looks like that I was not logged on to my domain network at work and hence it wasnt accepting me !!!